# Using strsplit with lapply

Tags: r, lapply, strsplit

I have a question with using strsplit with laaply function.
I'm using titanic dataset and wants to split name by ",","." and extract "Mr", "Mrs" and so on.

I tried this code and gives me error

```
lapply(data$Name, strsplit(data$Name, split = "[,.]")[[1]][2])
```

Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) :
object ' Mr' of mode 'function' was not found

However, this code works

```
lapply(data$Name, function(x)strsplit(x, split = "[,.]")[[1]][2])
```

[[995]]
[1] " Mr"
...

I don't know what's the difference between those two..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of `lapply` needs to be a function. The expression `strsplit(data$Name, split = "[,.]")[[1]][2]` is not a function, it is the ouput of `strplit()` applied to `data$Name` with your addtional arguments.

In your second example, which does have a (anonymous) function as the second argument, it is clear what `lapply` needs to do with each element of the first argument.

Consider:

```
data <- list(1,2,3)

lapply(data, paste0(data, "_")) # Error, paste0(data, "_") is a vector, not a function
lapply(data, function(x) paste0(x, "_")) # Works
```

```
[[1]]
[1] "1_"

[[2]]
[1] "2_"

[[3]]
[1] "3_"
```

Comment: Oh I thought strsplit() was function.. Is it not?

Comment: @TaekHwang `strsplit()` is a function, but `strsplit(data$Name, split = "[,.]")[[1]][2]` is not. Try `class(strsplit)` vs `class(strsplit(data$Name, split = "[,.]")[[1]][2])`.